# playframework: Difference between @Transactional annotation and JPA.withTransaction() method

Tags: jpa, transactions, playframework, playframework-2.0

We normally annotate action methods of controller classes with `@Transactional` if we are accessing Persistence Objects of `JPA`, or `EBean`. The question is when to use @Transactional annotation and when to use `JPA.withTransaction()` (assuming we are using JPA for persistence).
What is the difference between these two, and which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JPA.withTransaction for a block, @Transactional is for method or an action.

Comment: I don't think it's a major difference, I am talking about the functionality and architecture not code block scope.

Comment: As you can see at https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/TransactionalAction.java @Transactional wraps an action with JPA.withTransaction (with default parameter).

Comment: yes, but sometimes @Transactional annotation did not work and you have to use `JPA.withTransaction()`. Is't that true?